# How to adjust chain tension on a rohloff hub with semi-horizontal dropouts

Tags: chain, dropouts, rohloff

Not sure my question makes sense, I do not know how to call these dropouts. And I do not know much about Rohloff hubs and chain tension requirements.

My problem : my chain is too loose and fall off regularly. It is not torn, only 1000 km and I checked with the proper tool. But the problem appeared recently : even if it seemed loose to me when I acquired the bike, the chain did not fall off at this time.

I guess these dropouts are made to adjust chain tension, but I tried to unscrew them and they did not seem to want to move much. Since I was not sure, I did not insist.

[image: semi-horizontal dropout]

Comment: Certainly looks like the dropout is made to move. Did you loosen all 4 bolts holding it? Then firmly pull on the wheel and/or wiggle it sideways.

Comment: What bike frame is that?

Comment: @Michael no I did not, I was afraid of doing something wrong. It worked.

Comment: @whatsisname It is a Vagabond Grand Raid.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteRudant: Oh and by the way: Make sure the wheel is properly aligned i.e. the dropout position is the same on both sides. It’s easiest to verify by checking that the rim is centered between the chainstays and seatstays. Make sure you tighten the bolts sufficiently and check from time to time that the dropout hasn’t moved (maybe mark the position with some paint).

Answer (score 5):

They're swinging dropouts. When everything is set up right and in good condition, swingers and sliders make adjusting tension on a Rohloff or other IGH easy because nothing else about the cables and brake changes.

Loosen the pivot and sliding bolts on both sides. If the swinging isn't happening easily then, something is probably stuck or obstructing it, perhaps to do with how the hose or housings are attached to the frame, or the dropouts being stuck in place from not having moved in a while. Sometimes grooves in the paint or frame material need to be gently taken down with these styles.

The bolt threads and shoulders should all be lubricated. Grease is okay but it's a good application for anti-seize because they're usually big high-torque stainless fasteners.

On most swinging dropouts I'm aware of, it wouldn't matter that your fender stay is overlong past its clamp and is running into the pivot bolt, but I could imagine there being an exception. You'll want to double check that's not the obstruction.

Comment: I was afraid of doing something wrong, but the swinging happened easily once I loosened all bolts. Thank your answer and the additional advice.